# Is an Ubuntu Phone OS being developed or are plans limited to Ubuntu For Android?

Tags: phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ‘Ubuntu for phones’ and how can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

Things is getting a bit confusing. There are posts on blogs and websites about an Ubuntu Phone OS, which is a phone that runs on an Ubuntu OS solely. There are plenty of designs out there for Unity adapted to a smartphone. However, the only reference to phones on the Ubuntu website is the Ubuntu For Android page which seems to be a project that enables Ubuntu to run alongside Android and it is seemingly not an independence phone OS but a means to unite the desktop with the mobile platform. Are there really no plans for an independent Ubuntu Phone OS?